# MySQL simple query wrong

Tags: mysql

I need Help with this query which is not working for me and don't know why, can't find the error.

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `buscarchile`(dni int)
BEGIN
SELECT Nombre, Apellido FROM chile WHERE DNI = dni;
END
```

With this code, it gives me the name/Nombre and lastname/Apellido wheather it has the dni correct or not. I have tried this way also:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `buscarchile`(dni int)
BEGIN
SELECT Nombre, Apellido FROM chile WHERE DNI = @dni;
END
```

But wheather I enter the right dni or not it gives me no data, like it couldn't found anyone with that dni, but I know there is someone with that exact same dni.

Please help me with this, Thank you.

Comment: I think it may be getting confused between the name of the parameter and the name of the column you are checking. What if you change your input parameter name from "dni" to "dniMatch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the statement

```
SELECT Nombre, Apellido FROM chile WHERE DNI = dni;
```

there is a *name* conflict between column name `DNI` and variable name `dni`.

It would be a better practice to use `var_ColumnName` kind of practice for variables or procedural parameters.

Whether or not such practice is maintained, it would be more better if the *parameters* are read into local variables and use the same in SQL statements.

**Change your routine like this**:

```
delimiter //

create
  DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
  procedure `buscarchile`( dni int )
begin

  declare var_DNI int = dni;

  SELECT Nombre, Apellido FROM chile WHERE DNI = var_DNI;

end;
//

delimiter ;
```